# Getting one list per iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Very newbie with python here. I want to make a code that converts units from a txt file. The conversions are determined by the Dict variable. Can anyone explain me why my code generates one list per conversion and not one list with all the conversions in? I'm stack here for days guys. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you guys. below is my code and the output

Comment: Can you tell what output you are expecting.

Comment: I’ll second what @Vaibhavi said, and that it would be good to have the contents of your input file. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: Also, your variable names are all over the place. They should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` convention. There is no point in using `.get()` in the way you are, you could just use the standard syntax.

Comment: There are still more improvements to be made, I will write and share a refactored version of your program tomorrow :)

Comment: I would advice you to use better syntax as @AlexanderCécile says. Also use intuitive variable names before posting your code; Eg: here, "position" doesn't really store the position of anything.

Comment: @Circle Good point on the names themselves, yeah.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation guys. I'd change those variable names obviously,  this wasn't my final code. The output I'm expecting is to convert any units that are on a text from any txt file i open.

Comment: @Uni13 Why did you get rid of your code? Do you not want people to take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple mistake in your code. You are not updating your original list (new_list) with CONVERSION. This should work (all added/changed lines are denoted by "#####"):

```
size = {'mm':0.001, 'cm':0.01, 'm':1.0, 'km':1000} 
Dict={'size':'cm'} 
unit_in=Dict.get('size')
unit_in_value=size.get(unit_in)

with open('TEXT1.txt','r') as x:
    LIST=x.read().split() 
    new_list=[item.replace('.','') if '.' in item else item for item in LIST] 
    for i in range(len(new_list)):
        if new_list[i] in size:#######
            unit_out=new_list[i] ########
            print(unit_out)
            unit_out_value =size.get(unit_out) 
            print(unit_out_value)
            position=new_list[i-1] ##########        
            print(position)
            result=int(position)*unit_out_value /unit_in_value 
            print(result)
            CONVERSION=new_list.copy() ######
            CONVERSION[i-1] = result #####
            CONVERSION[i] = unit_in ######
            print(CONVERSION)
            new_list=CONVERSION ######
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
new_list = ['I', 'am', '16', 'm', 'but', 'i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'be', '1800', 'mm']
print(new_list)
CONVERSION = []
for i in new_list:
    if i in size:
        unit_out = i  # unit on the text
        print(unit_out)
        unit_out_value = size.get(i)  # text unit's corresponding value from the dictionary for the conversion
        print(unit_out_value)
        result = int(CONVERSION[-1]) * unit_out_value / unit_in_value  # calculation of the result
        print(result)
        CONVERSION[-1] = result
        CONVERSION.append(unit_in)
    else:
        CONVERSION.append(i)
print(CONVERSION)
```

Note that `CONVERSION[-1]` means the last element of `CONVERSION`.